# Consuming REST service using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a REST Service written in Java which returns an array of data in JSON like this:

```
[{"key":"London","value":"51.30"}]
```

Now I'm trying code an AngularJS REST clients using the AJS documentation. So far I've been able to invoke the REST service (I can see from the server logs) yet nothing is printed in the HTML page.
Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html  >
  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-resource.js"></script>
         <script language="javascript">


      angular.module('myApp',['ngResource']);
            function Ctrl($scope,$resource) {
              var Geonames = $resource(
              'http://localhost:8080/rest-application/rest/json', {     
               }, {
               query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
               create: { method: 'POST' }
            }
          );
          $scope.objs = Geonames.query();
         };
         Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope','$resource'];

  </script>
 </head>

    <body >
       <div ng-app="myApp">
              <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
                 {{objs.key}} - {{objs.value}}

              </div>
           </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried this example with several small variants taken from tutorials yet it is still not working. Any help ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get back from `query()` is an array so you should loop over it with `ng-repeat`

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
       <ul>
           <li ng-repeat="obj in objs">{{obj.key}} - {{obj.value}}</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Just my two cents but, this way you are repeating the `<ul>` structure, so you will have several `<ul>`'s each with only one `<li>`. Maybe placing the `ng-repeat` on the `<li>` would be better? What do you think? (Just talking semantics here)

Comment: @GonchuB you are 100% correct, i've modified my code

Comment: Thanks for your reply- I've checked out the result but it is still displaying anything, even if the REST service is being called. An alert of $scope.objs after the query() method displays an empty String.

Comment: Can you check if the server returns data? You can check that in the Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. Well from the Chrome console I can see an error message: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/rest-application/rest/json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. "

Comment: Solved it. By embedding it within the Web application works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Now it's time to read up on CORS. If you're using servlets, you can solve this using a servlet filter such as https://github.com/eBay/cors-filter. If you just want to test things, you can also disable web security in Chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: Embedding it within the Web application is another option, but it slows down your development because you always have to redeploy. What we do in fact is use Apache as a proxy to forward all requests to localhost:80/rest to localhost:8080/rest so you don't run into CORS errors

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's organize your code a bit:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngResource']);
// Controllers get their dependencies injected, as long as you don't minify your code and lose variable names.
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.objs = []; // We initialize the variable for the view not to break.
    // For the query example, you don't need to define the method explicitly, it is already defined for you.
    var Geonames = $resource('http://localhost:8080/rest-application/rest/json');
    // Resource methods use promises, read more about them here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
    Geonames.query({}, function(arrayResult) {
        $scope.objs = arrayResult;
    });
});
```

You have to adjust your html code with an `ng-repeat` directive to handle each item of your array:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
            <!-- object is a reference for each item in the $scope.objs array-->
            <span ng-repeat="object in objs">
                {{object.key}} - {{object.value}}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribute. I've tested the code with the changes; unfortunately it does not work and from the logs I can see that the REST service is not being called anymore.

Comment: My bad, you do need the `ngResource` module. Does it work that way?